# How could I convert many randomly generated integers into a string of an array in order to perform the forEach() method to check if age >= 18 [DESC]

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach, split

I am trying to experiment an unusual method of converting randomly generated integers into strings and then converting the strings into an array list with the generated numbers by using the split() method, this is so that I may perform a function on each element inside the array using the forEach() method.

My goal is that the forEach() method checks to see if all the randomly generated integers inside the array are greater than or equal to 18, otherwise return 'lower than 18', age

This is what I have come with so far and I'm stuck:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try</button>
```

```
var numbers1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25 + 1).toString()
var numArr = numbers1.split(",").map(createAnArray)

function createAnArray(item) {
  return parseInt(item)
}
console.log(numArr)

function myFunc(age) {
  if (age >= 18) {
   return "age suceeds", age >= 18;
  }
  else if (age != 18 || age === 17) {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'lower than 18', age;
  } else {
  return 'flop'
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = numArr.find(myFunc);
}
```

Comment: 18 is a number why you want to compare it against string array items? Why not integer array items?

Comment: Why `split(",")`? There are no commas in a number converted to string. And if you split every character they would all be less than 10.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing with current code?

Comment: @charlietfl if i must have made a typo, i apologise. it still does the same. i just don't know how to have multiple numbers generated inside an array seperated by commas. I just want to check to see if those generated numbers is >= 18 otherwise it does something else.

Comment: Any number in array meets the 18 or above...or do something for each one individually? The higher level exercise isn't making a lot of sense here. Start small and research the first step of how to create array of random numbers. There are cleaner ways using a loop than doing your string approach

Comment: So. I'm trying to have multiple numbers generated and then have them seperately be stored inside an array list, with their generated values and then have all of the values inside the array to be checked to see if they meet my condition which is age >= 18 or else..

Comment: @charlietfl that is fine, i appreciate your constructive feedback. thank you for assessing my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you probably want something like this

```js
function randomNumbers(maximum, minimum, arrlen) {
  return Array.from(   //  create an array 
    { length: arrlen }, // give it an optional length
    () => (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum) // generate random numbers in a range 
  );
}
console.log(randomNumbers(30, 15, 10));
```

Comment: I like what you did, but could you help make me understand what exactly is happening here ```(maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum)``` i assume, it's doing maximum value which is 30 - 15 for min and then adding 1 and the next part i'm clueless

Comment: Sure I will explain, `Math.random()` returns a random number between 0 and 1 (1 excluded), think of this as the base range and we want to find the equivalent number between the `min - max` , first we convert our range to be the same as Math.random by subtracting our (mini  from the max) and (mim from min which is 0) once we do that we will have two intervals our base interval 0-1 and (0 to maximum-minimum) to find the corresponding value we multiply whatever number we got from our base interval using Math.random by max-min

Comment: and  to include max number since our base interval 1 (max)  is excluded  we add 1 lastly we add the minimum number back again so that our calculated number is within the range,